# Automating Sklearn ML Model on GCP/Airflow

Tags: scikit-learn, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Right now I have one AI Notebook instance with 2 notebooks (one for training model, one for predictions and saving to BigQuery table for further purposes). I need to train and make predictions weekly (or train only once a month) and I do it by hand week after week.

How can I automate the process? I have my data prepared weekly via Airflow DAGs so all I need is:

1. Train model (monthly)
2. Make predictions (weekly)
3. Save predictions to BigQuery

I could use a helping hand as I am very new to GCP environment and would appreciate a simplified language :) Thanks a lot

I looked into some options such as notebook scheduling and airflow dag, but it is really hard for me to implement.

Answer (score 0):

GCP provides some Airflow operators to manage your AI Notebooks ([here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/mlengine.html) is the doc).

- MLEngineStartTrainingJobOperator: This creates a virtual machine that can run code specified in the trainer file, which contains the main application code
- MLEngineCreateModelOperator: This creates a new model
- MLEngineCreateVersionOperator: This creates a new version of an existing model
- MLEngineStartBatchPredictionJobOperator: This takes a file path (GCS) as input and use the model to make predictions and save result in a new file (in GCS).

Finally, you can use the operator [GCSToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html) to load predictions file in BigQuery.